# Emmet-vim not working with Plug

Tags: html, reactjs, vim, jsx, emmet

I am attempting to get the mattn/emmet-vim plugin working with the configuration I read in this article: https://drivy.engineering/setting-up-vim-for-react/

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
Plug 'mxw/vim-jsx'
Plug 'mattn/emmet-vim'
call plug#end()

let g:user_emmet_leader_key='<Tab>'
let g:user_emmet_settings = {
  \  'javascript.jsx' : {
    \      'extends' : 'jsx',
    \  },
  \}
```

I put the above in my `~/.vimrc`. Then ran Vim and installed the plugin with :PlugInstall.

But based on the docs and that article I should now be able to go into insert mode and type 
`h2.myHeader` + `<Tab>` and it should turn into `<h2 className='myHeader'></h2>`

But I'm not seeing it. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to type `Tab` and then `,` (comma) to trigger the expansion.

Thanks for asking this, the formatting in the article is a bit weird, so i'll update to avoid other people being confused. :)